# Angular how to add new property to item inside array while preserve other property

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I got a `data` property with 7 item inside an array and other property(`message, orderby...`). What I want to do is add a new property to the 7 item inside the array while preserve the other property.
Currently my item inside the array got this property `{id:"this is id"}`

[image: current data]

Expected output

```
data:
   0: {id:"id1", newProperty:"new"}
message:null
status:"success"
....
```

Note: This response is coming from an http.get method.

Comment: use the `rxjs map operator` on the web request, and then use `Array.map` on the array data.

Comment: `obsResp.map(obj => obj.newProp = 'prop')` and you can use this new property in the subscriptions.

Answer (score 1):

I am considering your variable name to be "response".

```
response.data = response.data.map(item => {
   return {...item, newProperty: newValue};
});
```

Here I have used spread operator to preserve your existing data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the forEach method to execute a provided function once for each element in the array. In this provided function you can add the new property to the element.

```
data.forEach(function (element) {
  element.newProp = "new";
});
```